# Get Data from two different tables on a condition

Tags: sql, join, oracle10g

I got situation like below:

Posts and like tables are respectively:

```
       -----------------         --------------------------
      | post_id | text   |      | post_id  | like  | person|
      -------------------        ---------------------------
      |   1     |  hello |      | 1        |  yes  | Jhon  |
      |   2     |  Haii  |      | 1        |  yes  | Sham  |
      |   3     |  I am..|      | 1        |  yes  | Ram   |
      --------------------      | 2        |  yes  | Mahe  |
                                ----------------------------
```

Now I want to get all posts and I want to know whether each post is liked by Sham or not.

So result will be:

```
           -----------------------------------
           | post_id | text  | liked_by_Sham  |
           -----------------------------------
           |   1     | hello |  yes           |
           |   2     | Haii  |  no            |
           |   3     | I am  |  no            |
           ------------------------------------
```

As I am new to SQL can anyone explain me how to do that. I tried it using Inner join but it doesn't work.

I tried with below query:

```
select posts.*,liketb.like 
from posts 
inner join liketb 
        on posts.post_id = liketb.post_id 
where liketb.person = 'Sham';
```

This query is giving only posts liked by sham.

Comment: instead of saying it doesn't work..please post your attempt

Comment: Inner join definitely not going to work for this.  How about an outer join?

Comment: @vkp Thank you for suggestion. I have posted my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7dd50/2)**

You need put the filter clausule on the `ON` section to get all post with `yes, no` or `null` when no match. And use **[nvl](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)** to convert all `NULL` to `'no'`

```
SELECT p."post_id", p."text", nvl(l."like", 'no') as liked_by_sham
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN liketb l
       ON p."post_id" = l."post_id"
      AND l."person" = 'Sham'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| post_id |   text | LIKED_BY_SHAM |
|---------|--------|---------------|
|       1 |  hello |           yes |
|       3 | I am.. |            no |
|       2 |   Haii |            no |
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `left join`, with `case`. `like` is a keyword. Make sure it is properly escaped.

```
select p.post_id, p.text, 
case when l.like = 'yes' then l.like else 'no' end as liked_by_sham
from posts p
left join liketb l on p.post_id = l.post_id and l.person = 'Sham';
```

Comment: instead of `CASE` you may simplify with `NVL(l.like, 'no') as liked_by_sham`